# Mounting synology disks in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mount, lvm, synology

I have some files on synology disk that I would like to recover with extundelete.
I have mounted the raid1 setup. So on the disk is two raid storages (md2 and md3) and they are connected to one with lvm. I try to get the lvm going. I think it doesn't like the md2p1. I tried to mount md2p1, but it doesn't mount, so I thnik it's some garbage. How could I make that work that LVM would find the other device?

```
sudo lsblk -o name,uuid,mountpoint
NAME        UUID                                   MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                
├─sda1      bb4b1f59-9349-4e59-cced-5de7ca715931   
├─sda2      291dec99-01d5-7031-cced-5de7ca715931   
├─sda5      46288321-39d3-353d-7014-c3a9333d1c33   
│ └─md2     8s9LfU-Egt2-sbtJ-1zkH-ewqb-LjRT-xZ2RC2 
│   └─md2p1 8da77aa4-43ff-4cd1-81f0-f311284e0b04   
└─sda6      a7ff03a3-29c2-a100-ecdd-c31c151ca783   
  └─md3     Eu0fsK-Cu1W-3PCw-ZEV6-80fL-05rf-H0qlcE 
sdb                                                
├─sdb1      e29faa0c-a7b4-4851-a17d-75c20238edc2   /
├─sdb2      ce06f4bb-5f73-423b-9794-b94a1e47d4f8   
└─sdb3      6089A7F658D702D4                       
sdc                                                
└─sdc1      09d3c590-3a6a-4436-8718-7c14ab0e282b 

sudo lvs
 Couldn't find device with uuid 8s9LfU-Egt2-sbtJ-1zkH-ewqb-LjRT-xZ2RC2.
LV   VG     Attr      LSize Pool Origin Data%  Move Log Copy%  Convert
lv   vg1000 -wi-----p 2,72t
```

Answer (score 0):

I was once confronted by this problem, and what I've done is cross-compiled `extundelete` and installed it on the synology.

Another way may be to use `kpartx` so your system will recognize the correct device name.

I remember synology used to assemble RAID parts using `mdadm`, not LVM directly (it may have changed since).  If you use LVM directly and modify the filesystem, you may have to reconstruct the RAID.